# $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is connected (understanding the proof )

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness

I'm reading a sketch of the proof that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is connected and it goes like this:

1) Fix $x_1\in X$ and verify that the function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\ y\to (x_1,y)$ is continuous;

2) Suppose that $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}=A\cup B$ where $A,B\neq\emptyset$ are open and disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and fix $(x_1,y_1)\in A, (x_2,y_2)\in B$; verify that $\{(x_1,y)\colon y\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq A$ and $\{(x,y_2)\colon x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq B$;

3) Show that from (1) and (2) follows that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is connected.

Now, I've managed to prove (1) and (2) but I don't understand how from these it follows that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is connected so I'd appreciate any hint.

Also, is this proof applicable to the general case of $X\times Y$ where we know that $X,Y$ are connected metric spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: where does $(x_1, y_2)$ go?

Yes, this proof idea works to prove that a product of two connected topological (not necessarily metric) spaces is connected.

Comment: $(x_1,y_2)\in A\cap B$ so we get a contradiction but what I don't understand is where does (1), the continuity of the function $y\to (x_1,y)$, enter the picture.

Comment: @lorenzo The continuity just is used to see that $\{(x_1,y): y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is connected (as a continuous image of $\mathbb{R}$).